# Alias domain names for site collections

Tags: 2013

I have one web application and several host based site collections under it.

**abc1.xxx.com**

**def1.xxx.com**

**ghi1.xxx.com**

**jkl1.xxx.com**

**mno1.xxx.com**

Now I need to configure Sharepoint/IIS to make these site collections to work with a specific subdomain. Like

**abc1.xxx.com** should work when I type **abc.xxx.com**

**def1.xxx.com** should work when I type **def.xxx.com**

I want to do this without renaming(copying/moving) site collections. Main reason is when I'll do a new version of a site let say **abc2.xxx.com** I want to keep the old one **abc1.xxx.com** and just simply point **abc.xxx.com** to **abc2.xxx.com** and be done.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set-SPSiteURL abc1.xxx.com abc.xxx.com -zone Custom`
Add IIS binding for `abc.xxx.com`
Update DNS pointing `abc.xxx.com` to your SP server